# Pull-up resistors needed for quasi-bidirectional push-pull PCF8575/PCF8574(A)

Tags: pullup, push-pull, bidirectional

I wonder if I need pull-up resistors when using the PCF8575 I/O extender.

It's not directly mentioned in the datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcf8575.pdf). The datasheet does remark that the I/O ports are ***quasi-bidirectional push-pull design***, but I'm not sure if that says anything about internal pull-ups.

The PCF8575 is connected to ACPL-247 opto-couplers for input (collector/emittor side) and NCV8402D mosfets for output.

Comment: Surely whether it needs push-pulls is at least partly dependent on your design? If they're used as outputs they won't need them. If they're used as inputs, it depends what they're connected to.

Comment: "I'd add them just to be sure" To be sure of what?

Comment: @DiBosco: MOSFET gate pull up for outputs. Input side is connected to an opto-coupler transistor, pull up would go on the collector leg to the PCF port.

Comment: @m.Alin: As in better safe than sorry.. But that is more like a breadboard approach. When designing a PCB I don't like second guessing this..

Comment: Open collector opto?

Comment: The opto is just a transistor so I think by default that means open collector. Datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1695482.pdf

Comment: Right, so you already have pull-ups for the inputs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real need for pull-ups would be to ensure that either the output starts or goes high when the output is not driven or to force the pin into a particular state when the pin has an open input.

The spec sheet says "At power on, the I/Os are high. In this mode,
only a current source (IOH) to VCC is active." That is, the maker already thought of that for you, **assuming you don't need it to start out low**....

However, if your particular design needs to hold a particular pin in some state while you switch it around, that is another matter.

Comment: Start position is not really important. I can set these over i2c at start up.

Comment: @svenema well assuming one pin doesn't turn on the 'Launch ICBM" N-Channel MOSFET when high... yes.

Comment: But, in the case of an input. The port is connected to an opto-coupler transistor, this probably means that the port will float when the input is not driving the led in the opto-coupler. So I may need a pull-up for that situation?

Comment: If the opto is pulling the pin to ground you should be ok assuming you initialize properly first.

Comment: I think an photo-transistor is not conducting whenever the LED is off, so I think it's not pulling anything to the ground. It's when the internal LED turns on that it pulls to ground, given that the emitter is connected to ground.

Comment: I missed your earlier reply. Hahaha, I promise, I will not launch any ICBMs. Ok, so I'll add the pull-up. The more I think about it the more sense it makes...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need additional pull-up resistors.

The PCF8575's datasheet says that:

> At power on, the I/Os are high.

So the outputs are in a known state.